# How to use Ajax.ActionLink() for bootstrap collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, razor

How can I use Ajax.ActionLink for Bootstrap Collapse Effect?
I used it for modal. But for collapse I have to user "href" attribute for actionLink which causes page redirect and content will not load.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("OrderDetails", "OrderDetails","Orders",
new {id = @item.OrderId},
    ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", AllowCache = false, InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "Content_"+ @counter },
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary", role="button", data_toggle="collapse" , href="#Panel_"+@counter ,aria_expanded="false", aria_controls="collapseExample" })
```

and target collapse:

```
<div class="collapse bg-danger" id="Panel_@counter">
    <div id="Content_@counter">

    </div>
</div>
```

What can I do?

Comment: add a preventDefault (if possible)

Comment: I think you're going to want to add the asp.net tag so that this gets shopped around by the right people.